# How to use embedded Scrollspy in Materialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, material-design, scrollspy

Fundamentally this question can be summed up fairly easily. Currently it works as shown in the following image and jumps from `topicTimer(0)` to `topicTimer(1)` and so on.

[image]
How would I make it both highlight the topic and the question within said topic, `topicTimer(0)` and `questionTimer(0:0)` for example?

Comment: Please post your relevant code. Hard to help you debug without seeing your code.

Comment: @Spartacus It's not fixing an issue I have, I'm asking if it is possible to do something, and how it would be done.